# Using jsdoc annotation, how do I specify the type to output of generic function when calling

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, jsdoc

I've got code similar to:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.thing').forEach(el => el.style.color = 'red');
```

The type hint system in VsCode marks `el.style` as missing from `Element`. I can fix this with:

```
/** @type {NodeListOf<HTMLElement>} */
const things = document.querySelectorAll('.thing');
things.forEach(el => el.style.color = 'red');
```

It seems wrong to create a var for the sole purpose of keeping VsCode's type system happy.

If I were using typescript, I think I could do

```js
document.querySelectorAll<HTMLElement>('.thing') // etc...
```

Is there a way to tell VsCode's type system which type I expect out of a generic method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [jsdoc cast](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-checking-javascript-files.html#casts) for this:

```
// @ts-check
(/** @type {NodeListOf<HTMLElement>} */ (document.querySelectorAll('.thing'))).forEach(el => el.style.color = 'red');
```

Note that you must wrap the target of the cast (`(document.querySelectorAll('.thing')`) in parens so that the type applies to the correct expression.

Comment: I did not know about that typescript jsdoc page! Would have saved a lot of trial and error...

Comment: Shame you have to include `NodeListOf` and there's a potential to incorrectly cast the types, but still useful.